# 60's or older story about two kinds of mutant telepaths

Tags: story-identification, telepathy, mutant

Now this is a very old story. It was old when I read it in the late 60’s or the early 70’s. 
There are mutants who are telepaths and have small “antennas” which make them rather conspicuous (they can try to hide the antennas under their hair, or under hats and such things, but is does not work very well) so they are hunted, and a second type who do not have antennas. Non-mutant humans do not know of the second kind. If I remember properly, one mutant of the first kind finds out about the second kind, so he is hunted by them, too. 
I don’t remember much else, and not at all how the story ends.

Comment: Well, I went to the wiki page you indicated. You are right, this is indeed my story. But I was also right : it says in this page that there are two kinds, one with "tendrils" (what I remembered as "antennas") an the other kind is "tendrilless", so the wiki page agrees with what I remembered. But you also say the same thing together with its contrary, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Anyway, if you would care change your comment into an answer, I'll accept it since you did find the right title.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the plot of A.E. Van Vogt's 1940 novel *[Slan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slan)*.

There are two types of "Slans": one type has golden antenna-like "tendrils" that they try to hide, but not always successfully, the way that you describe. Because of their psychic powers and their obvious difference, the main antagonist, world dictator Kier Grey, has the slans hunted to near extinction. Note that this novel came out in 1940.

As the book progresses, we find that there are some slans without "tendrils" who are able to hide themselves from non-slans.

> They are not allies-- the tendrilless slans hunt the true slans as ruthlessly as regular humans!

Although *Slan* is far from my favorite novel, it is a well known classic because of its electrifying effect on SF fandom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101669/discussion-between-spencer-and-user14111).